# Add sidebar to homepage layout?

Tags: php, magento

I've updated my `page.xml` file to include the categories template in the left column like so:

```
<page_one_column_home translate="label">
    <label>All One-Column Home Layout Pages</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-home.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
    </reference>
    ...
</page_one_column_home>
```

Added this code:

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="category.sidebar" as="categorySidebar" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

I've also updated the homepage template file to print the HTML generated in the 'left' column:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left'); ?>
```

However this isn't working; the result is nothing is printed in the left column on the homepage layout.

Comment: hi Ozzy. Whether you want to display all categories to the left side instead of top (which is by default in magento) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to modify your own base template.

Goto

```
Magento CMS -> pages -> home
```

Change design tab, select layout 2columns-left or 3-columns as required.

You can then use the left navigation, however it may need some changes. If you check the left.phtml it checks to see if there's any current category, if there's not it will not show.

You can make a copy of that template, for example:

```
copy catalog/navigation/left.phtml to catalog/navigation/left-home.phtml
```

You could then change from this:

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php //if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
```

this will make the left nav show all top level categories for you.

You then add this into your CMS -> Pages -> home layuout updates XML.

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav"  as="categorySidebar" after="currency"     template="catalog/navigation/left-home.phtml"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the alternative solution. I have already made my own alternative. But I'm leaving this question open because I'm trying to get to the bottom of why this code `$this->getChildHtml('left')` doesn't work when I've added it to the 1-col layout phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav"  as="categorySidebar" after="currency"     template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </block>
    </reference>
    </default>
```

Also Clear magento cache